# how to format NTFS partition in Debian?

Tags: partitioning, debian, formatting

how to format NTFS partition in Debian?

Comment: only terminal commands please

Answer (score 5):

```
# apt-get install ntfsprogs
# mkfs -t ntfs /dev/part
```

Comment: thanks appreciate ur answer how can i quick format ?

Comment: @Abdul Khaliq: just re-create fs with 2-nd command (it is quite quick)

Comment: `mksf.ntfs -f /dev` check `mkfs.ntfs --help`